# Is there a way to generate an integer numpy array by multiplying a float array with one that will remove the need of a float for result?

Tags: arrays, numpy, integer, multiplication

multiplication of a numpy float array for an integer and producing an integer array with results

standard multiply function, when starting with a float array, generates a float result, yet i start with an array having hundreth digits (i.e.  0.0x )  no smaller than that (smallest decimal part is greater than 0.01)   this array has to be used after multiplication by 100, 1000, 10000  and up for several orders of magnitude, so the resulting array will NOT NEED to be float; int array will work a lot faster during subsequent repetitive iterations. I am looking for the proper way to create an int array, provided the necessary float starting array will generate only integer elements

Comment: `(arr * 100).astype(int)` ?